# Explanation of success/failure terms with C# Actions?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, parameters

I found the method below in a Windows Phone 7 C# sample.  In it you can see the terms *success* and *failure* used inside the method.  I tried *Go To Definition* with either term and Visual Studio did not jump to a definition for either term.  I tried searching Google using the terms "Action", "success", "failure", "C#", and "parameter" and did not find anything useful.  Are *success* and *failure* in this context macros or something similar?  Where can I get an explanation of what they do and how to use them?  Note, the tooltip help when hovered over *failure* shows "**parameter Action<string> failure**".

```
    public void SendAsync(string userName, string message, Action success, Action<string> failure) 
    {
        if (socket.Connected) {

            var formattedMessage = string.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4}",
                SocketCommands.TEXT, this.DeviceNameAndId, userName, message, DateTime.Now);

            var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formattedMessage);

            var args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            args.RemoteEndPoint = this.IPEndPoint;
            args.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            args.Completed += (__, e) => {
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
                    if (e.SocketError != SocketError.Success) {
                        failure("Your message can't be sent.");
                    }
                    else {
                        success();
                    }
                });
            };
            socket.SendAsync(args);
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are delegates that are being used as "callback functions". Basically, they are functions that are provided to another function that can be called inside that function. Perhaps a smaller sample would make more sense:

```
static void PerformCheck(bool logic, Action ifTrue, Action ifFalse)
{
    if (logic)
        ifTrue(); // if logic is true, call the ifTrue delegate
    else
        ifFalse(); // if logic is false, call the ifFalse delegate
}
```

False is printed in the below example, because `1 == 2` evaluates to false. So, `logic` is false within the `PerformCheck` method.. so it calls the `ifFalse` delegate. As you can see, `ifFalse` prints to the Console:

```
PerformCheck(1 == 2, 
            ifTrue: () => Console.WriteLine("Yep, its true"),
            ifFalse: () => Console.WriteLine("Nope. False."));
```

Whereas this one will print true.. because `1 == 1` evaluates to true. So it calls `ifTrue`:

```
PerformCheck(1 == 1, 
            ifTrue: () => Console.WriteLine("Yep, its true"),
            ifFalse: () => Console.WriteLine("Nope. False."));
```

Comment: Understood but where is the code that executes when failure() or success() are executed during the anonymous method defined in the callback?  In addition to trying "Go To Definition" for "success" and "failure" I did a full solution search and can't find any function/method/etc. defined as "success" or "failure".  So what happens when those Actions fire?

Comment: They are part of the call. Go to the callsite for this method (wherever it is called) and see what is passed in. If they are straight up method bodies.. great. If not, they will be delegates that you can "Go to definition" on to see their implementations/assignments.

Comment: Great example. If created and expanded on it in a dotnetfiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UhL3ua

Comment: Thanks @GFoley83. Its great to see questions I answered nearly two years ago are still viewed and helpful to others :)

Answer (score 2):

You can think of `Action` (and also `Func`) as variables that hold other methods.

You can pass, assign and basically do anything to an `Action` that you would any other variable, but you can also call it like a method.

Say you have two methods in your code:

```
public void Main(){
    Action doWork;
    doWork = WorkMethod;
    doWork();
}

private void WorkMethod(){
    //do something here
}
```

You assign WorkMethod to the action like you would do any assignment to the variable. Then, you can call doWork as though it were a method. It isn't particularly useful in this example, but you can probably see how all the benefits of standard variables apply.

You use an `Action` and a `Func` in pretty much the same way. The only real difference is that an `Action` represents a `void` and a `Func` requires a return type.

You can also use generics. For example `Action<int>` respresents a method with the signature

`void methodName(int arg){}`

`Action<int, string>` would be

`void methodName(int arg1, string arg2){}`

`Func` is similar, `Func<int>` would be:

`int methodName(){}`

`Func<string, int>` would be:

`int methodName(string arg){}`

It's important to remember that the *last* type in the `Func` definition is the return type, even though it appears first in the actual method signature.